# Bsearch function issue in C

Tags: c++, bsearch

I am trying to use bsearch but the result of search keep staying NULL.My array of names is sorted alphabetically.I am new in C and need your help to understand where am I wrong.

Here is an array

```
// arrays of children's names
char *chBamba[] = { "Bambale1", "Bamb2", "Bamb3", "Bambook4", "Bambookle5" };
char *chBisli[] = { "Bislile1", "Bischick2", "Bislile3", "Bis4" };
int nBamba = sizeof(chBamba) / sizeof(*chBamba);
int nBisli = sizeof(chBisli) / sizeof(*chBisli);
// array of workers
Worker a[] = { { "Printf", 10, NULL, 0 } ,{ "Bisli", 20, chBisli, nBisli },
{ "TapooChips", 3, chBamba, nBamba },{ "Bamba", 19, chBamba, nBamba } };
```

This is struct

```
typedef struct{
char name[LEN]; // worker's name
int salary; // worker's salary
char **childArr; // array of children names
int numChildren; // number of children}Worker;
```

Compare function

```
int compareNames(const void* child1, const void* child2){
  char* ch1 = (char*)child1;
  char* ch2 = (char*)child2;
  return strcmp(ch1, ch2);
}
```

And the bsearch

```
  char childName[10];
  char* nameFound;
  printf("Please enter a child name to search for :");
  scanf("%s",childName);

  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    nameFound =(char*) bsearch(childName,a[i].childArr, a[i].numChildren, sizeof(a[i].childArr)/ sizeof(a[i].childArr[0]), compareNames);
  }
```

It is C not C++.That what I am learning right now.I am using VS 2015 and it works for both C and C++.I am editing some changes to get it work correctly and compile.
So compare is

```
int compareNames(const void * s1, const void * s2){
const char *key = (char*)s1;
const char * const *arg = (char**)s2;
return strcmp(key, *arg);
```

}

and the bsearch is

```
nameFound = (char*)bsearch(childName,a[i].childArr, a[i].numChildren, sizeof(char*), compareNames);
```

Comment: There is no need to typecast `bsearch`. It returns `void*`.

Comment: @RoadRunner: Correct. Still the OP most likely use either a C++ compiler, or MS-VS.

Comment: yea I use VS2015 and there it asks for casting

Comment: @alk That is true. In that case, casting is required.

Comment: @GordonIgor Its good to see you got your code working. You should also use `scanf("%9s", childName);` instead, to avoid buffer overflow.

Comment: Your updateed solution is provoking UB. In case it seems to work, that's just pure bad luck. Consider running the code using a memory checker (like Valgrind for example) to convince yourself.

Comment: This isn't C, but C++. Mind the initialisation of `a`. This won't compile in C. Question retagged.

Answer (score 1):

The compare function is being passed *pointers* to the array's elements.

From [`man bsearch`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bsearch.3.html):

> The `compar` routine is expected to have two arguments which point to the  key
>          object  and  to  an  array  member ....

The array's elements are of type `char *`, so the compare function should look like this:

```
int compareNames(const void * pvchild1, const void * pvchild2)
{
  const char ** ppc1 = (const char **) pvchild1; // casting necessary with C++
  const char ** ppc2 = (const char **) pvchild2; // casting necessary with C++

  return strcmp(*ppc1, *ppc2);
}
```

To additionally cover the case that the array contained null-pointer values you could do:

```
  ...

  return strcmp(ppc1 ?*ppc1 :"", ppc2 ?*ppc2 :"");
}
```

Call `bsearch()` like this:

```
  char * p = childName;
  nameFound =(char*) bsearch( // casting necessary with C++
    &p,
    a[i].childArr, 
    a[i].numChildren, 
    sizeof *(a[i].childArr), 
    compareNames
  );
```

---

Also as a side note: The code you show defintily *isn't* C but C++, as this

```
Worker a[] = { 
 { "Printf", 10, NULL, 0 } ,{ "Bisli", 20, chBisli, nBisli },
 { "TapooChips", 3, chBamba, nBamba },{ "Bamba", 19, chBamba, nBamba }  
};
```

won't compile in C, but give the error:

```
error: initializer element is not constant
```

Comment: If i change to what you typed I receive en error"Exception thrown at 0x0F581340 (ucrtbased.dll) in HW3_GordonIgor.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x34736942.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."

Comment: @GordonIgor: You don't want to pass `NULL`  to `bsearch()`  (as address of the 1 element of the array to be searched) as you would do for the 1st element `{ "Printf", 10, NULL, 0 }`.

Comment: @GordonIgor: To further debug this you might like to compile with symbols, run the code inside a debugger to trace through the program(s) line by line inspecting the values of the relevant variables to learn what is really going on. If then a *specific* question arises feel free to come back here.

Comment: After a sort the NULL array at index 2 so it doesn't even pass the first array and gives me an error I have typed